# Order by cases- sorting by dynamic column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

In my procedure I have:

```
SELECT
    Col1,
    Col2,
    (Col1+ Col2) AS Col3
FROM Table1
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN @SortColumn='Col1' THEN Col1 END ASC,
    CASE WHEN @SortColumn='Col3' THEN Col3 END ASC -- PROBLEM HERE
```

The problem is that I can't sort by column which doesn't exist in `Table1`. I tried with `CASE WHEN @SortColumn='Col3' THEN 'Col3' END ASC` but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 4):

Use a CTE or subquery:

```
with t as (
      select col1, col2, (col1 + col2) as col3
      . . .
     )
select t.*
from t
order by (case when @SortColumn = 'Col1' then col1 end) asc,
         (case when @SortColumn = 'Col2' then col2 end) asc;
```

Comment: Possible typo: + / =

Answer (score 2):

Another sql-server option is CROSS APPLY

```
SELECT
    Col1,
    Col2,
    ca.Col3
FROM Table1
CROSS APPLY( 
      SELECT (Col1 + Col2) AS Col3
) ca
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN @SortColumn='Col1' THEN Col1 END ASC,
    CASE WHEN @SortColumn='Col3' THEN ca.Col3 END ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that I can't sort by column which doesn't exist in Table1. I tried with CASE WHEN @SortColumn='Col3' THEN 'Col3' END ASC but it doesn't work either.

If your column types (`Col1` and `Col2`) are `varchar`, you should be able to use a straight `CONCAT()`:

```
...
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN @SortColumn='Col1' THEN Col1 END ASC,
    CASE WHEN @SortColumn='Col3' THEN CONCAT(Col1,Col2) END ASC
```

In other cases, you can make use of the `CONVERT()` function to turn the columns into strings, and then concatenate.

Comment: Not sure CONCAT works with integers (supposing col1 and col2 are integers, OP does not specify)

Comment: @MaxiWheat Well... since the OP didn't specify what he/she wanted, there ought not to be a case for down-voting my solution, right? Sure - I made an assumption, but with a lot of the questions here on SO, assumptions are necessary. In any case, I have now clarified my assumption.

Comment: Actually... The OP uses `(Col1 + Col 2) as Col3`, so using CONCAT() in any case is probably overkill.